# How to join and pivot, link and group a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

A part of this question was previously answered but I have an updated request here

[How to pivot, link and group a table with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594542/how-to-pivot-link-and-group-a-table-with/45595070?noredirect=1#comment78150152_45595070)

I have a table **beta** with cols Id, Parent, Name, Level

```
CREATE TABLE [beta](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Parent] [int] NULL,
[Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Level] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Beta] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample contents are

```
Id Parent   Name             Level
1   NULL    Clinical         1
2   NULL    Custom           1
3   NULL    Medicare         1
4   NULL    Validation       1
5   1       Medicaid         2
6   2       CD               2
7   3       Specialty        2
8   5       Fraud            3
9   2       Institutional    3
10  8       Professional     4
```

Id is unique. There are up to 4 levels. Each `Name` can be traced back to level 1 through the `Parent` value. Level 1 `Parent` is always `NULL`.

I need to join table [beta] to table [Enum]

```
CREATE TABLE [Enum](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Enum] [Varchar] (6) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Enum] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC,
    [Enum] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Sample content is

```
Id Enum
1  000001
5  000001
8  000001
10 000001
2  000002
6  000002
```

I want to join these two tables and retrieve result like below. The result shows the distinct `Enum` and all the `level` they are associated with.

```
Enum   Level1   Level2   Level3 Level4      
000001 Clinical Medicaid Fraud  Professional
000002 Custom   CD       NULL   NULL       
...............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to pivot like below

```
select enum,[1] as Level1, [2] as Level2, [3] as Level3 , [4] as level4
from 
(select E.enum,
B.level,B.name from
beta b join enum e
on b.id=e.id)s
pivot 
( max(Name) for level in ([1],[2],[3],[4]))
p
```

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/ANM72842)**</kbd>